# Azure Data Factory & Snowflake: NULL datetime values

Tags: sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I'm using the copy activity to copy Snowflake tables to SQLServer. That requires a staging storage.

It all works fine except for one table, which has got a `TIMESTAMP_NTZ` column. It gets correctly mapped to a `DATETIMEOFFSET` column in SQLServer. But it fails with this error when there is a `NULL` in that column.

```
Failure happened on 'Sink' side. 
ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,
  Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
  Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,
  Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,
    Type=System.InvalidOperationException,
    Message=The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type datetimeoffset of the specified target column.,
    Source=System.Data,
      Type=System.FormatException,
      Message=Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTimeOffset.,
      Source=System.Data,
        Type=System.FormatException,
        Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.,
        Source=mscorlib
```

As far as I debugged this the error is caused by the `NULL` in the `datetime` column. It seems that the intermediate format in the storage is `CSV`, and that its encoding for `NULL` is misinterpreted by the second leg of the copy (storage to SQLServer, receiving an `''` instead of a `null`).

The only solution I see is to copy all as `NVARCHAR` and then use `TRY_CAST` on SQLServer to convert it back to what it should be.

Is there any other solution that works within the COPY activity?

**UPDATE**

This is the CSV that gets generated by Snowflake

```
"dtCreateDate","dtLastUpdateDate"
"","2023-03-08 11:59:59.563"
"","2023-03-08 11:59:59.563"
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that setting a snowflake format option makes this work.

`NULL_IF = ()`

That's not in the [snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location#format-type-options-formattypeoptions) nor in the [adf docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-snowflake?tabs=data-factory#snowflake-as-the-source).

Its now creating it as

```
"dtCreateDate","dtLastUpdateDate"
,"2023-03-08 11:59:59.563"
,"2023-03-08 11:59:59.563"
```